# Strange behaviour with os.join()

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, path

I've noticed odd behaviour with Pythons os.join(). in that I'm adding a year and filename to a path. Here's my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

#------------------------------------------------
def file_walk(root, ext):
  # Walk file with me, Laura Palmer!

  fList = []
  for current, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for file in files:
      fname = os.path.join(current, file) # this works fine, yeah!

      src = os.path.isfile(fname)
      if src:
        if fname.endswith(ext):
          fList.append(fname)

  return fList


myFolder = r"d:\temp\test"
myExt = ".html"
myYear = "2019"

allfiles = file_walk(myFolder, myExt)

for theFile in allfiles:

  sourceFile = theFile
  destinFile = os.path.join(myFolder, myYear, theFile)

  print sourceFile
  print destinFile
  print 


myFile = "bookmarks_06_05_2019.html"
print os.path.join(myFolder, myYear, myFile)

# EoF
```

As strings, they work fine (see last line), but as paths, not so well :(

Output I'm getting from print destinFile

> d:\temp\test\bookmarks_01_26_2018.html
>
> d:\temp\test\bookmarks_05_06_2014.html
>
> d:\temp\test\bookmarks_06_05_2019.html

I'm expecting the follow:

> d:\temp\test\2019\bookmarks_01_26_2018.html
>
> d:\temp\test\2019\bookmarks_05_06_2014.html
>
> d:\temp\test\2019\bookmarks_06_05_2019.html

Can anyone point me in the right direction of where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Print the contents of `fList`. You'll see they don't look like `"bookmarks_06_05_2019.html"`.

Comment: Actually, you *are* printing those contents. Did you not notice that they don't look like the string that "worked fine"?

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks, I see where I've gone wrong now! D'oh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`theFile` is an absolute file path. If all you want from it is the base name, use:

```
destinFile = os.path.join(myFolder, myYear, os.path.basename(theFile))
```

Note that `os.path.join` returns the last absolute argument with any relative arguments after that one combined in a path. This is why the result didn't have the 2019 component.

Comment: I realised that now :rolls eyes::, and I had written a function for the basename (omitted from above) but it was returning the absolute path.